# ¿Cómo podría validar un input de tipo (teléfono) usando jQuery validation plugins?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myForm').validate({
            rules: {
                telf: {
                    required: true,
                    telf: true
                },
           }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Si el número necesita el formato de los Estados Unidos, el [plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/phoneUS-method/) lo trae por defecto:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#miForm" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      phoneUS: true
    }
  }
});
```

---

Si necesitas un formato personalizado tienes que agregarlo tú mismo.

Ejemplo:

#### HTML

```
<form id="miForm">
<input type="text" name="nomTelefono" id="idTelefono" class="required" placeholder="1-222-333-4444"/>
<button id="btnEnviar">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

#### jQuery

El regex 
`/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/`

crea un validator de números con el siguiente formato:

`1-222-333-4444`

```
$.validator.addMethod('customphone', function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/.test(value);
}, "Por favor entre un número de teléfono válido");

$(function() {
    $("#miForm").validate({
        rules: {
            nomTelefono: 'customphone' //nombre del elemento y del método creado
        }
    });
});
```

**<kbd>[Ver Demo: JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/acedano/w2fgtLsn/)</kbd>**